# Изменение позиционирования

Tags: html, css

Есть контейнер `div` с двумя блоками `p` которые позиционированы относительно левой стенки контейнера, я захотел переместить первый блок относительно правой стенки, но не получается. Почему так происходит?

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

div p:first-child {
    right: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p class="q1"></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: потому что у ВАс получается что у p:first-child - значение: left:0, right:110px, нужно "избавится" от left

Comment: @user190134 Подскажите каким способом? Я поставил left:none; но без результатно

Answer (score 1):

Как написал user190134 к первому селектору применялось сразу 2 значения right и left. Нужно было задать для left значение auto.

Comment: Вы можете принять текущий ответ (галка слева от поста) если он вас устраивает: при этом неважно, что вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

div p:first-child {
    right: 110px;
    left: auto; /* override */
}
```

```html
<div>
<p class="q1"></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```